# How multi column select in join table (two tables switch)

Tags: mysql

I want to switch 2 tables on `MAIN_USER_TABLE` in `typeCode` column. 
But MySQL `LEFT JOIN` is not working with `CASE` or `IF`.

So I tried using a sub-query, but CASE cannot get multiple columns. Using subqueries for each column seems too be inefficient. I'd like to know if there's another efficient way.

This is for windows, running `MySQL5`

```sql
SELECT A.userNum,
    CASE
    WHEN A.typeCode='TYPE01'
    THEN (
        SELECT userName, age, gender
        FROM TYPE01_USER_TABLE
        WHERE userNum = A.userNum
        )
    WHEN A.typeCode='TYPE02'
    THEN (
        SELECT userName, age, gender
        FROM TYPE02_USER_TABLE
        WHERE userNum = A.userNum
        )
    END
FROM MAIN_USER_TABLE A
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything looks so difficult, make usual UNION

```
SELECT A.userNum, userName, age, gender
FROM MAIN_USER_TABLE A,TYPE01_USER_TABLE
WHERE A.typeCode='TYPE01' AND userNum = A.userNum
UNION ALL 
SELECT B.userNum, userName, age, gender
FROM MAIN_USER_TABLE B,TYPE02_USER_TABLE
WHERE B.typeCode='TYPE02' AND userNum = B.userNum
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation as to what is union doing so that others can understand how to use it properly?

Comment: In this case UNION operation combine all records from the first "SELECT" with all records from the second "SELECT". From the first query we will receive records of users with 'TYPE01' value in the field typeCode, from the second with 'TYPE02' value in this field. Therefore for first query userName, age, and gender we will get from TYPE01_USER_TABLE, for second we will get from TYPE02_USER_TABLE.  You can get more details here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html